# Docusign API : how to get captive recipient signature details

Tags: docusignapi

I am browsing through  docusign REST API and this is what I am trying to find.

1. I need to check if captive signer (not the user account) signatures are already available.
2. If signature available is adopted, i need to clear captive signer signature details, so docusign can force the user to draw his signature.
3. If signature available is already drawn signature, proceed with signing ceremony.

I was able to find details on how to DELETE captive signer

```
https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/captive_recipients/signature
```

But before DELETE can be executed, i want to check the status of signature.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is this needed in your workflow? Most people use a unique clientUserId per envelope to ensure that the captive recipient is forced to adopt a new signature each time.

Comment: Hi Andrew,
For better UX, our business has asked us to force the users to draw their signature only if the previously provided(if any) one is not a drawn signature. We have several forms , where the user can come back multiple times to sign the applications. This is the reason to look for an api that can provide signature details of captive recipients( they are not the members/users in our account).

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a list of signatures for the user:

   /accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/signatures

More info here: [Get User Signatures API Call](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20List%20of%20User%20Signature%20Definitions.htm?Highlight=signature)

You'll get back an array with these objects:

```
{"userSignatures" : [{
"signatureId":"String content",
"adoptedDateTime":"String content",
"createdDateTime":"String content",
"initialsImageUri":"String content",
"signatureFont":"String content",
"signatureImageUri":"String content",
"signatureInitials":"String content",
"signatureName":"String content",
"signatureType":"String content",
"signature150ImageId":"String content",
"initials150ImageId":"String content",
"isDefault": "String content"
}]
}
```

You can then proceed to your signing if the array isn't empty.